# Calculated distance giving the wrong values

Tags: php, google-maps

I have a function in `PHP` which calculates the distance between two places.

Here is the **php code :**

```
function distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2) {
   $earth_radius = 6371; 
   $delta_lat = $lat2 - $lat1 ;
   $delta_lon = $lon2 - $lon1 ;

  $distance  = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) + cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($delta_lon)) ;
  $distance  = acos($distance);
  $distance  = rad2deg($distance);
  $distance  = $distance * 60 * 1.1515;
  $distance  = round($distance, 4);
  return $distance = $distance * 1.609344;
 }
```

It gives good calculations around `25 km`, but around `500 km` the calculations are wrong.
My other question is `it really giving miles or kilometers?`

For example this [map](http://maps.google.co.in/maps?hl=en&q=morbi%20to%20surat&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&biw=1280&bih=923&um=1&ie=UTF-8&sa=N&tab=wl) gives a distance of `443 km` from `Morbi` to `Surat`, but the function gives me a result of `274 km`

Comment: I'm not the math genius but this article helped me when I was trying these things out: http://www.meridianworlddata.com/Distance-Calculation.asp

Comment: 6371 is the (approximate) radius of the earth in kilometres, so the answer should be in km. Do note that any geometrical calculation is the *straight-line* distance not the *by-road* distance. You are calculating the straight line between two points (if the calculation is correct); Google Directions give the by-road distance, which will always be longer.

Comment: `@Andrew Leach` thanks for great comment. but any other formula to calculated perfect distance ? (in php)

Comment: @veer do you need the road distance or the straight distance ?
If you need the road distance then you can try to use google api, otherwise use the haversine forumula ...

Comment: morbi IS 274 km away from surat, so your distance function is correct.

Comment: @Veer: I was using my iPad, which makes checking things more difficult.

Comment: i need the road distance @HamZaDzCyberDeV

Comment: @Veer I edited my answer, try my script, and read the Google Api Distance Matrix ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, now that's clear that you want the road distance, we can give you a proper answer, to get the result, you can use the [Google API Distance Matrix](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/), you have different options and parameters, you have to figure out which suits you the most, be aware that there's some limitation (for the free edition):

```
<<
The Distance Matrix API has the following limits in place:
100 elements per query.
100 elements per 10 seconds.
2 500 elements per 24 hour period.
>>
```

However for the purpose of answering your question i wrote a simple PHP script that gets a XML file and parse the distance/duration with SimpleXMLElement ...

```
<?php
$start = "morbi";   // You can either set lon and lat separated with a comma ex: 22.814162,70.834351
$destination = "surat";
$mode = "driving";  // Different modes: driving,walking,bicycling (be aware that some of the modes aren't available for some poi's ...)

$xml = file_get_contents("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=$start&destinations=$destination&mode=$mode&language=en-EN&sensor=false");
$data = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$distance = $data->row->element->distance->text;
$time = $data->row->element->duration->text;
if(empty($distance) OR empty($time)){
    echo "Oops, this mode ($mode) isn't available ...";
}else{
    echo "The distance between $start and $destination is $distance and the travel duration while $mode is $time .";
}
?>
```

Hope this was helpful :)